# I can't see the net card using “ifconfig -a”

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, drivers

My computer had two network cards and runs the Ubuntu 14.04. The OS had named the two cards p4p1 and p5p1 respectively. They worked well until the old motherboard was replaced yesterday. After the new motherboard was inserted and the OS booted, there is only one card(p4p1) shown in the "ifconfig -a". All the two physical port blink well.

I have tried the ways found from Internet but still not succeed. But now I have come to some points although I have no idea of them. I have also boot a OS on USB disk and there only showed one card(eth0) in the "ifconfig -a".

The "lspci" shows this:

```
  03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
  04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
```

and the "lspci -v" shows this:

```
   03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
        ...     
        Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 0c-c4-7a-ff-ff-04-fb-16
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e

   04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
       ...
       Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-00-7a-ff-ff-04-00-00
```

This seems to me that the second device has no driver in use. But the two devices are the same then why not the driver used in the first diced not respond to the second device?

I have tried re-install the driver for this type device but nothing is different after that.

Anybody know how to resolve this may so kind to help me!

Comment: When you say you reinstalled the drivers, what drivers did you install?  Is there a reason you aren't using the native driver in the kernel?  Can you do an `lsmod` and add it to the question?

Comment: Have you tried swapping the positions of the cards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a new motherboard and the question was solved.